# Class not found exception while creating a table in HBASE

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, jar, hbase

After succesfull installation and configuration of HBase on top of HDFS on our local servers, I did the same configuration on our OVH VPS machines, however I am getting a strange error.

Entire setup is starting fine, however, when I try to create a table from hbase shell, I am getting  following error:

> 2017-05-20 11:59:19,256 ERROR
>   [RpcServer.FifoWFPBQ.default.handler=29,queue=2,port=16000]
>   master.MasterRpcServices: Region server prdhad001,16020,1495274311971
>   reported a fatal error:
>   ABORTING region server prdhad001,16020,1495274311971: The coprocessor
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.coprocessor.AggregateImplementation
>   threw java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.coprocessor.AggregateImplementation
>   Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.coprocessor.AggregateImplementation
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)

and after that entire hbase is getting corrupted and throwing numerous errors. It seems that it doesn't load some jars properly , however jar is present inside lib folder.

> My configuration :
>       Virtualization: kvm     Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
>          CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
>               Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64
>         Architecture: x86-64      Hadoop 2.7.3   HBase 1.3.0
>
> export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin   export
>   HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop   export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
>   export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin   export
>   HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME   export
>   HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME   export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
>   export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME   export
>   HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native   export
>   HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"   export
>   HBASE_CLASSPATH=/usr/local/hbase/lib/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, inside the hbase-site.xml I had following property added:

```
<property>
    <name>hbase.coprocessor.region.classes</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.AggregateImplementation</value>
 </property>
```

which is used for the coprocessor, which we don't use at the moment. Removing this part fixed the issue, however, I guess that if we would like to use coprocessor in the future we might encounter this issue again do any other help will bee appreciated.